# Using ThreadPool vs other forms of multithreading in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I have a real-time application built in c#.NET and sql as DB.

The application has three modules:

1. Grabbing under-vehicle images(UVSS) using a camera,
2. Detection of  license plate number (ALPR)
3. Recording Driver info video(DIC).

We first receive a trigger from ADM 6060 which then activates the cameras(via code)and then these three modules happen simultaneously using Threads(and then stored into db). Lastly we display these on WinForm.

I am currently using a two threads:

1. Thread 1 for monitoring trigger value received by ADM
2. Thread 2 for grabbing live Under-vehicle images

Further, on receiving appropriate trigger value from ADM6060, 
I create Two tasks - for ALPR detection and DIC video.

I cannot post the entire code due to comapny's policy but here's a snippet:

I have 2 threads in Form1:

```
ThreadStart tsmain = new ThreadStart(this.ServiceCaptureImage);

thread = new Thread(tsmain); 

ThreadStart tsmain1 = new ThreadStart(this.Draw_Bitmap); 

continuous = new Thread(tsmain1);
```

thread.start() and continuous.start() are executed in form_Load.

```
private void ServiceCaptureImage()
{ 
  try{ 
         while(true)
         { 
            if(bdata[0]==false)
                {
                  var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ALPRdetect()); 
                  var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DICcapture()); 
                   Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
                } 
          } 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex){
          MessageBox.show(ex.message)
        }

}
```

I manually counted the number of cars that were detected by the system.
 In a total of 70 cars passed: 53 were totally detected(ALPR, under-vehicle and DIC), 4 cars went undetected, 9 cars ALPR was missing and in the remaining under-vehicle were missing.

The efficiency achieved so far is 84%, in some cases the application only performs ALPR but not UVSS or vice-versa.

What could be the possible reason? 
Also, should i be using ThreadPool in this case?

Comment: When 1 task doe snot run at all then the other one is probably blocking something. From the question we can't tell much.

Comment: Would ThreadPool class be a better alternative?

Comment: `Task` uses the tread pool too. Basically you should start all threads using `Task.Run` 90% of the time.  If you want to tweak some aspect of how these run then you want `Task.Factory.StartNew` but [use this with caution](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). From a "performance" perspective, it depends. You'll need to test it and see which is faster. Without some kind of code example though this is very hard to answer. The only time I would create a `Thread` class is if I'm targeting an old version of .net, TPL is the way to go these days

Comment: I have2 threads in Form1ThreadStart tsmain = new ThreadStart(this.ServiceCaptureImage);thread = new Thread(tsmain); ThreadStart tsmain1 = new ThreadStart(this.Draw_Bitmap); continuous = new Thread(tsmain1);thread.start() and continuous.start() are executed in form_Load.
private void ServiceCaptureImage(){
//some code
try{
while(true){
if(bdata[0]==false){
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ALPRdetect());
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DICcapture());
Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
}
}
 catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.show(ex.message)}

Comment: What do you mean by effeciency is 75%? how do you measure that?

Comment: I manually counted the number of cars that were detected by the system. In a total of 70 cars passed: 53 were totally detected(ALPR, under-vehicle and DIC), 4 cars went undetected, 9 cars ALPR was missing and in the remaining under-vehicle were missing.